# Proper way of setting delegates in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, delegates

I would like to know what is a proper way of setting delegates in the ViewModel in MVVM pattern in Swift.

I'm instantiating the ViewController from another class:

```
let viewModel = DashboardViewModel()
let viewController = DashboardViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
```

My ViewModel:

```
protocol DashboardViewModelType {
    var items: [Item] { get }
    var reloadDelegate: DashboardDataReloadDelegate? { get set }
}

protocol DashboardDataReloadDelegate: class {
    func reloadData()
}

class DashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModelType {

    var items: [Item] = []

    weak var reloadDelegate: DashboardDataReloadDelegate?

    init() {
        loadItems()
    }

    func loadItems() {
        let databaseFetcher = DatabaseDaysFetcher()
        databaseFetcher.getDays(onData: { (items) in
            self.items = items
            reloadDelegate?.reloadData() //delegate is nil here
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

and ViewController:

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: DashboardViewModelType?

    init(viewModel: DashboardViewModelType) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.viewModel!.reloadDelegate = self // it is executed after 
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

}

extension DashboardViewController: DashboardDataReloadDelegate {
    func reloadData() {
        print("data reloaded")
    }
}
```

So the main problem is that if I want to inject the viewModel in another class I'm instantiating the viewModel when delegate is not yet set. Would it be better to declare `loadItems` inside the `DashboardViewModelType` protocol and then call this function from the init or viewDidLoad inside the ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could inject `DatabaseDaysFetcher` in the `init` for the `DashboardViewModel` and then as you say, move `loadItems` to the `DashboardViewModelType` protocol.

Then when you call `loadItems`, it should callback in to the caller.
Then use [weak self] in the `loadItems` callback.

This would negate the need for the `delegate`.

```
protocol DashboardViewModelType {
    init(databaseFetcher: DatabaseDaysFetcher)
    func loadItems(completion: ([Item]) -> Void, error: (Error) -> Void)
}

final class DashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModelType {

    private var databaseFetcher: DatabaseDaysFetcher

    init(databaseFetcher: DatabaseDaysFetcher) {
        self.databaseFetcher = databaseFetcher
    }

    func loadItems(completion: ([Item]) -> Void, onError: (Error) -> Void) {
        self.databaseFetcher.getDays(onData: { (items) in
            completion(items)
        }) { (error) in
            onError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw is it ok to put all methods inside this protocol? As far as I know it's better to use protocols when injecting dependencies, right? So I should put all necessary methods in the protocol and use protocol type instead of downcasting to the exact ViewModel?

Comment: Correct - the reason being you want to `code to an interface` as it will help you you write testable code e.g. you can write a fake DatabaseDayFetcher that uses a dictionary rather than API or Database call and focus on testing that one unit. Also, it helps create re-usable code and easy to change code.